# Como usar um svg (ou div) para clicar e selecionar o checkbox correspondente

Tags: php, javascript, formulário, checkbox

Tenho um formulário que é um filtro de busca de receitas. Nesse filtro tenho um grupo de checkbox referente à categoria:

```
<form method="get" action="/busca">
  <h4>Categoria</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="entrada"> Entrada
  <input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="principal"> Principal
  <button type="submit">Buscar Receitas</button>
</form>
```

Eu queria ao invés de aparecer os checkbox, aparecesse uma imagem (svg) para clicar, e ao clicar na imagem ele marca o checkbox correspondente. Estou usando biblioteca do fontawesome. Aí o DIV que queria que fosse clicavel, seria assim:

```
<div class="categoria" id="entrada">
  <i class="fas fa-apple"></i><br/>
  Entrada
</div>
<div class="categoria" id="principal">
  <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><br/>
  Principal
</div>
```

Aí ao clicar nos divs, ele seleciona o checkbox correspondente.

E um item a mais, quando clicar no div, ele mudasse a classe do css, para ficar vermelho por exemplo. Poderia adicionar a classe ".clicado" e ao clicar novamente, remove essa classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um jeito "meio gambiarra" de fazer, vou utilizar alguns conceitos que o @hugocsl utilizou.

Cada `<div>` terá que ter seu `id` e `onclick` para chamar a função, que estará enviando um parâmetro, que é o `id`. Com a padronização dos `id` dos `<button>`, sempre começando com `btn-`, é só concatenar o `id` enviado com o btn e disparar o gatilho de marcação do `checkbox` e inserir um novo estilo:

```js
function trocar(id){
   $('#btn-' + id).trigger('click');
   $("#" + id + " i").closest( ".categoria" ).toggleClass("clicado")
}
```

```css
.clicado{
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/busca">
  <h4>Categoria</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="entrada" id="btn-entrada"> Entrada
  <input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="principal" id="btn-principal"> Principal
  <input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="sobremesa" id="btn-sobremesa"> Sobremesa
  <button type="submit">Buscar Receitas</button>
</form>
<div class="categoria" id="entrada" onclick="trocar(this.id)">
  <i class="fab fa-apple fa-2x"></i><br/>
  Entrada
</div>

<div class="categoria" id="principal" onclick="trocar(this.id)">
  <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-2x"></i><br/>
  Principal
</div>

<div class="categoria" id="sobremesa" onclick="trocar(this.id)">
  <i class="fas fa-cookie fa-2x"></i><br/>
  Sobremesa
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Legal, valeu.Tem alguma forma de fazer mais "dinâmico"? É que na verdade vão ser varias categorias, entrada, princpal, sobremesas, sopas, etc., aí acredito que exista alguma forma de fazer com que seja mais dinamico ne? Brigadão!

Comment: esse dinâmico, seria ter mais opções de escolha, deixar de uma forma mais visível?

Comment: seria para simplificar o codigo, por exemplo, se tiver 10 categorias, terei que criar 10 funções certo? não tem tipo como eu fazer uma função "genérica" que funciona para todos? (não sei se deu para entender minha duvida)

Comment: alterei minha resposta, utilizando a forma que o @hugocsl explicou.

Comment: show, funcionou, só tive que fazer uma alteração, aqui " $("#" + id + " i").toggleClass("clicado")" estava aplicando o css só no icone, alterei para  $("#" + id + " i").toggleClass("clicado") "$("#" + id + " i").closest( ".categoria" ).toggleClass("clicado")", alterei a resposta